# Installing Facebook APK in Genymotion

Tags: android, facebook, android-emulator, genymotion

I want to install Facebook APK to Genymotion. Using Drag&Drop or adb it fails with INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE. I have followed instuction on http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952 and installed ARM Translation Installer. After this, Facebook APK is installed successfully but when I launch it, it crashes. In log, I have found

```
"1341-1341/com.facebook.katana:nodex A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000000b4 (code=1), thread 1341 (ok.katana:nodex)"
```

Answer (score 0):

please see below link and follow the steps:-

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps.

1. Change PATH system variable to path of tool i.e.    `parent-Directories/to/tools`.
   Go to My Computer-->Properties-->Advances System Settings-->System Variables-->PATH.
2. RUN-->cmd and change your current directory to /tool ( tools directory should have adb.exe ) 
   http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Directories-in-Command-Prompt
3. Install just one virtual device in Genymotion Virtual Device Manager and run that virtual device.
4. Run the command,  `adb install  full-path/yourAPK.apk`
5. In case of more installed virtual devices, your fourth step would be
   `adb -e install full-path/yourAPK.apk`

Comment: They complain about specific problem and you tell them how to install ANY app... wth.

Comment: He want to install the Facebook .apk file to Genymotion  and due to some errors can't do that, I just told him an alternative way of doing that. So what is wrong?

Comment: Try your own advice and you will see what's wrong. The app won't run.

Comment: I just told the method which works for me. M not supposed to tell someone something which don't work. And every answer here, doesn't solve each of every ones problem. hope you will understand.